# Given vectors $ \bar{u} $ and $ \bar{v} ≠ 0 $ show that there exists a unique choice of vectors $ \bar{x} $ and $ \bar{y} $ such that

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

- $ \bar{u} = \bar{x} + \bar{y} $
- $ \bar{x} \perp \bar{v} $
- $ \bar{y} \parallel \bar{v} $

I'm not sure how to interpret the question. Is this looking for a unique $ \bar{x} $, $ \bar{y} $ that satisfies all of the above criteria?
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Very often, the answer to "show that there exist ..." is found by asking "how can we build ...". Here you need an $y$ parallel to $v$, so $y = \alpha v$, then the first equation gives $x$, and you need to choose $\alpha$ to ensure the second condition.

Comment: Thank you. With this now clarified I will give it a shot.

Comment: You're taking MATH 226? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, precisely, you're trying to decompose $\vec u$ as a sum of two vectors, one parallel to $\vec v$ and one orthogonal to it. (The usual buzz word involved here is *projection*.) Here's a hint on how to proceed:

Write $\vec u = c\vec v + \vec x$ with $\vec x\cdot \vec v = 0$. Try to solve for $c$ and then for $\vec x$.

Comment: I added my work down below. If you have a chance and are willing to look over it that would be great. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done. If you are willing to look it over for me and let me know if it is coherent or not that would be awesome.

$ \bar{y} = a\bar{v} $

$ \bar{u} = a\bar{v} + \bar{x} $

$ \bar{x} \cdot \bar{v} = 0 $

$ (\bar{u} - a\bar{v}) \cdot \bar{v} = 0 \implies \bar{u} \cdot \bar{v} - a(\bar{v} \cdot \bar{v}) \implies a = \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}}{|\bar{v}|^2}$

$ \bar{x} = \bar{u} - \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}}{|\bar{v}|^2}\bar{v}$

Checking conditions:

$ \bar{y} \parallel \bar{v} \implies  \bar{y} = a\bar{v}$

$ \bar{x} \perp \bar{v} \implies (\bar{u} - \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}}{|\bar{v}|^2}\bar{v})\cdot \bar{v} \implies 
\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v} - \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}}{|\bar{v}|^2}|\bar{v}|^2 \implies \bar{u} \cdot \bar{v} - \bar{u} \cdot \bar{v} \implies 0 = 0 $

$ \bar{u} = \bar{u} - \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}}{|\bar{v}|^2}\bar{v} + \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}}{|\bar{v}|^2}\bar{v} \implies \bar{u} = \bar{u}$

Comment: Yes, it's fine, except for issues of style.  With the $x$ and $y$ you've defined, you have all the necessary conditions.